# Не найдена таблица "nat", при добавлении правил в iptables

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

Пытаюсь сделать подключение в интернет на сервере с помощью OpenVPN. Настраиваю сервер по инструкции с интернета.

При добавлении этого правила для маршрутизации трафика из сети OpenVPN:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Выдает эту ошибку:

```
iptables v1.6.0: can't initialize iptables table `nat': Table does not exist (do you need to insmod?)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
```

Я пробовал:

```
apt-get install iptables*
```

Не помогло.
Одно решение в инете было, которое пробовал тоже выдает ошибку:

```
root@s2e24dbab:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys# modprobe ip_tables
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:586 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab127.2/modules.dep.bin'
modprobe: FATAL: Module ip_tables not found in directory /lib/modules/2.6.32-042stab127.2
```

Дистрибутив и версия:

```
root@s2e24dbab:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys# cat /etc/issue
Debian GNU/Linux 9 \n \l
root@s2e24dbab:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys# cat /etc/debian_version
9.5
```

Как мне добавить это правило?

Comment: Что выдает "iptables-save | grep \\*"

Comment: попробуйте этот ответ - https://superuser.com/questions/813323/iptables-module-ip-tables-not-found-for-root

Comment: @Hellseher,
команда выдаёт следующее:
*filter,
*raw,
*mangle

Comment: Забыл добавить, что сервер виртуальный (openvz)

Comment: @Hellseher,  superuser.com/questions/813323/ не помогло. Нет каталогов, о которых там шла речь...

Answer (score 1):

Модуль ядра ip_tables не загружен (приведу пример с моей машины)

проверяем версию ядра:

```
~# uname -n
4.17.3-200.fc28.x86_64
```

Смотри какие таблицы уже активны

```
~# iptables-save | grep \*
*nat
*mangle
*raw
*security
*filter
```

Cмотрим документацию iptables:

> Dependencies
>
> iptables requires a kernel that features the ip_tables packet filter.
>   This includes all 2.4.x and later kernel releases.

проверяем наличае модуля:

```
~# lsmod | grep iptable
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_raw            16384  1
iptable_security       16384  1
```

Можно расширить фильтр:

```
~# lsmod | egrep -i ip.*tab
ip6table_nat           16384  1
nf_nat_ipv6            16384  1 ip6table_nat
ip6table_mangle        16384  1
ip6table_raw           16384  1
ip6table_security      16384  1
iptable_nat            16384  1
nf_nat_ipv4            16384  1 iptable_nat
iptable_mangle         16384  1
iptable_raw            16384  1
iptable_security       16384  1
ip6table_filter        16384  1
ip6_tables             28672  5 ip6table_filter,ip6table_raw,ip6table_nat,ip6table_mangle,ip6table_security
```

думаю, вам стоит обновить ядро, если чего то из перечисленного не хватает:

```
~# apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y
~# apt-get install linux-image-flavour
```

**Ссылки**

- https://netfilter.org/projects/iptables/index.html
- https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ. 
Я работаю на VPS и не могу обновить ядро. (забыл указать это в вопросе)
Команды lsmod | egrep -i ip.*tab и lsmod | grep iptable никаких значений не возвращает.
Уже много разных ответов на похожий вопрос испытал, в большинстве случаев у меня нет каких-либо каталогов, либо еще что-то...

Answer (score 0):

Благодаря:

```
~# iptables-save | grep \*
*mangle
*raw
*filter
```

Стало ясно, что таблицы `nat` нет и самостоятельно из контейнера его добавить нельзя. Это может сделать только хост, прописав соответствующую команду в конфиге для моего VPS.